# -Webkit-scroll bar + overflow + JQuery scrollTop returns always zero

Tags: jquery, html, webkit, css

I've been working on this bug whole day, and couldn't solve it.

Have a JQuery scrollTop animation script, that detects $(window).scrollTop() value and do some animation and if click on button scrolling back to top.
 $(this).click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},"fast");
    });

This works normally great. and i always get a scrollTop value... Until ->

When using custom -webkit-scroll bar for your browser, you have to
set in the css

**html** -> overflow: hidden
**body** -> position: absolute, overflow-y:scroll, overflow-x:auto

the html hierarchy is just normal html->body-> div container - > div content etc.

Now since the browser scrollbar is removed, and have your own customized scrollbar,
the scrollTop value always returns zero.

Have been trying all I can think of, no matter what other code I tried, the scrollTop value returns always zero.

So nothing is animating, and nothing is scrolling back.

**Anybody know how to get the value when using the custom **browser*** -webkit-scrollbar for scrolling back to top?*

Answer (score 1):

You're no longer scrolling the window, you're scrolling an internal element, so you should try:

```
$(html).scrollTop()
$(body).scrollTop()
```

and see if 0 changes

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you remove `overflow: hidden` and `position: absolute` from your `html` and `body` CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug which hasn't been fixed yet completely.
Check here
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9248

and check the last comment which shows this demo (http://maisqi.com/outros/bugs/chrome/CHN6) which still fails in webkit based browsers.