# Scroll Offset of Overflow Hidden Document

Tags: javascript, css, dom

CSS

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden
}
```

Setting above CSS in a page removes scroll from window [but triggers it on body], hence

```
 pageOffset =  (window.pageYOffset && { X: window.pageXOffset, Y: window.pageYOffset }) || {},
 dElementOffset = (dE && { X: dE.scrollLeft, Y: dE.scrollTop }) || {},
 dBodyOffset = (dB && { X: dB.scrollLeft, Y: dB.scrollTop }) || {};
```

[db = document.body, dE = document.documentElement]

None of the above code gives the number of pixels scrolled. Is there a way to determine scroll values in such cases? http://jsbin.com/zayem/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output [Need to load it in a separate html file; Linked it just for understanding]

Comment: By removes scroll from window, do you mean the scroll event or the scrollbar? Because while the horizontal scrollbar is removed the window scroll event still fires as there is still a vertical scrollbar http://jsfiddle.net/5JtHp/

Comment: My Problem is almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809106/webkit-scroll-bar-overflow-jquery-scrolltop-returns-always-zero

Answer (score 0):

`document.documentElement.scrollLeft` works for me. I tested it.

Also, your resizing columns are lagging.